# CiviEvent DB Error after Update

Tags: civievent, upgrade

After update to CiviCRM 4.7.10, now getting a DB Error: syntax error when trying to access CiviEvent registration links.  Any ideas would be very helpful.

```
- /home/carolinasgps/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976):
PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: syntax error", -2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id
as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
- /home/carolinasgps/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564):
DB_Error->DB_Error(-2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id,
contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...")
- /home/carolinasgps/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php
(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -2, NULL, NULL, "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id,
contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`,...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi there!  To solve your problem, we'll need to see the expanded debugging information.  In CiviCRM, please go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace", and press "Save".  Repeat the problem that caused your error, and you'll see much a much more detailed error.  Please update this question with the expanded error and backtrace - and don't forget to disable debugging/backtrace when you're done!

Comment: Looking at the path in the error message - are the two sets of 'www' correct? If not, then something is awry with your Resource URLs or Directory paths.